# Ошибка с URL на сайте

Tags: php, wordpress

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в сложившейся ситуации. Есть сайт http://alex-90.kz. Но там присутствует баг: почти все ссылки ведут не на `http://alex-90.kz`, а на `http://alex`. Сайт написан на WordPress. Как исправить данный недочет?

Comment: Скорее всего, написали хрень в конфиге. Посмотрите константу WP_SITEURL - должна быть просто "/".

З.Ы. не стоит употреблять словосочетание "написан на WordPress" - глупо звучит.

Comment: @ImirofF, а где находится эта константа?

Comment: ищи с помощью тотала, у него есть функция поиска слов в файлах  
ps я так постоянно делаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вообще это в конфигах в самом WP выставляется. заходишь в настройки
http://wp.local/wp-admin/options-general.php и там есть два поля "Адрес WP (URL)" и "Адрес сайта (URL)" Ну дальше думаю понятно..